# Как создать объект в php с определенным названием?

Tags: php, объекты

У меня есть список массивов которые содержат в себе такие данные

```
[field_data_field_task_status] => Array
    (
        [table] => field_data_field_task_status
        [num] => 1
        [alias] => field_data_field_task_status
        [join] => views_join Object
            (
                [table] => field_data_field_task_status
                [left_table] => node
                [left_field] => nid
                [field] => entity_id
                [extra] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [field] => entity_type
                                [value] => node
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [field] => deleted
                                [value] => 0
                                [numeric] => 1
                            )

                    )
```

обратите внимание на `join`он называется `views_join Object`

теперь хочу добавить еще один массив в список с объектом такого же типа

делаю следующее

```
$query->table_queue['taskweightdata']['join']->table = 'task_kanban_sort';
$query->table_queue['taskweightdata']['join']->left_table = 'node';
$query->table_queue['taskweightdata']['join']->left_field = 'nid';
$query->table_queue['taskweightdata']['join']->field = 'taskid';
$query->table_queue['taskweightdata']['join']->type = 'LEFT';
$query->table_queue['taskweightdata']['join']->extra = array(
    0 => array(
        'field' => 'uid',
        'value' => $user->uid,              
    ), 
    1 => array(
        'field' => 'pageId',
        'value' => 'tasks'
    ) 
);
```

но мой массив содержит такие данные

```
Array
(
    [table] => task_kanban_sort
    [alias] => tk_sort
    [join] => stdClass Object
        (
            [scalar] => views_join
            [table] => task_kanban_sort
            [left_table] => node
            [left_field] => nid
            [field] => taskid
            [type] => LEFT
            [extra] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [field] => uid
                            [value] => 487
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [field] => pageId
                            [value] => tasks
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

то есть `[join] => stdClass Object` вместо `[join] => views_join Object`

как это исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`views_join` - это тип объекта. Объекты в PHP создаются с помощью ключевого слова `new`. Допустим, структура вашего массива сохранена в переменной `$arr` - тогда создадим экземпляр класса `views_join` следующим образом:

```
$views_join = new $arr['field_data_field_task_status']['join'];
```

Если теперь распечатать значение переменной $views_join, то вы увидите необходимый набор свойств, которые теперь можно при необходимости перезаписать *(а так же добавить новые свойства в объект)*:

```
$views_join->table = 'task_kanban_sort';
$views_join->field = 'taskid';
$views_join->type = 'LEFT';
$views_join->extra = [
    ['field' => 'uid', 'value' => $user->uid],
    ['field' => 'pageId', 'value' => 'tasks'] 
];
```

По окончании редактирования свойств объекта `views_join` вам останется подставить объектную переменную $views_join в значение ключа `join`, и распечатать массив *(для визуального контроля полученной структуры)*:

```
$arr = [
    'field_data_field_task_status' => [
        'table' => 'field_data_field_task_status',
        'num' => 1,
        'alias' => 'field_data_field_task_status',
        'join' => $views_join
    ]
];

print_r($arr);
```

Результат:

```
Array
(
    [field_data_field_task_status] => Array
        (
            [table] => field_data_field_task_status
            [num] => 1
            [alias] => field_data_field_task_status
            [join] => views_join Object
                (
                    [table] => task_kanban_sort
                    [left_table] => node
                    [left_field] => nid
                    [field] => taskid
                    [extra] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [field] => uid
                                    [value] => $user->uid
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [field] => pageId
                                    [value] => tasks
                                )
                        )

                    [type] => LEFT
                )
        )
)
```

---

[*См.демо*](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c96edd7e66895a0f724ecbb49e80d27c38871367)